# Cocos2D - CCAnimation: which frame is being displayed right now?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm doing a sprite animation. The code is:

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay: 0.1f];
CCAnimate *animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];
[sprite runAction: repeat];
```

I want to know which frame of the animation is being displayed when I click on the sprite. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CCSprite method isFrameDisplayed](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_sprite.html#a8ae05177e6e0669821e6cfcd1124bd14) to compare the current CCSpriteFrame with another. You'll have to keep the frames array around to do the later comparison. Unfortunately Cocos2D does not support testing if the n-th frame of a particular animation is displayed out of the box, nor does it tell you the filename of the currently displayed CCSpriteFrame.

Comment: sorry to bump this post, however how do you make sure your frames array 'stays around' I'm creating my frames array like so: `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *bunsenAnimFrames;`

and adding the frames in one method, however when I try to use the method you suggested from another method the array has been emptied... :/

Comment: Don't worry... wasn't allocating and initing my array properly... all sorted now!